# Is it possible to save the format of the article?

Tags: joomla-3.x, helix3

I'm making my first Joomla website and I'm here to ask you this question: since every article will have to have the same format, is there a way to save it, so I don't have to remake it everytime I write a new article?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].

Comment: If I unverstanden you correctly I would use overrides for this 
 https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

If your Design is more komplex you can dry a Page builder: https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/joomla-page-builder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to save Templates for Articles.

You can save one of your Articles as a 'template' and make it unpblished so that it doesn't appear on the public view of the website. Then instead of creating a `New` article you can open the 'template' article and then click on `Save as Copy` to start working on a new copy of the template as your new article.

Depending on the Editor you are using for your website, some of the popular ones have Templates as a built-in feature. You need to look at what Editor you are using and then research if and how their article/content templates works.

And then there are extensions in the JED that provide article templating. A quick search brought up Regular labs Content Templater, https://docs3.regularlabs.com/contenttemplater/getting-started/introduction as possible contender but there are others.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been very helpful!